# C++: Bass library userinput location

Tags: c++

I am trying to get my code to take an input from the console and input it here in this function so that i do not have to hard code 1 mp3 for every song i want.

```
 HSAMPLE sample = BASS_SampleLoad(FALSE, "D:/Music&Movies/Music/You.mp3", 0, 0, 1, BASS_SAMPLE_MONO);
```

this is what i want it to do when a user inputs in the console. I dont want to have to hard code it like is already done.
I would like to have it like this.

```
  string userinput;
   cin >> userinput;      //but this will not work because it cannot take this 
 HSAMPLE sample = BASS_SampleLoad(FALSE, userinput, 0, 0, 1, BASS_SAMPLE_MONO);
```

Comment: For >10k users, here are more attempts by OP to explain: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351701/bass-play-mp3-from-user-given-filepath-c

Comment: @Yunnosch It should be in a text book, how not to ask and answer questions on SO. This time the question is asked much more clearly, but I think some of the previous posters should have worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just use the `c_str` method of `string` to get a C-style string.

```
string userinput;
cin >> userinput;
HSAMPLE sample = BASS_SampleLoad(FALSE, userinput.c_str(), 0, 0, 1, BASS_SAMPLE_MONO);
```

Comment: thank you very much i figured it was an easy solution